# See Azure DevOps WorkItems/Tasks in Planner?

Tags: azure-devops, azure

We are using Microsoft Teams and Planner since a while. Now we are migrating from Bitbucket/Bamboo to Azure DevOps.

If I create a Team in Microsoft Teams with a Planner-Board, I can see all my tasks in Planner. But when I have tasks in Azure DevOps, I can't see this tasks in Planner. Teams and Azure DevOps is connected to Azure AD. Is there a way to show DevOps-Tasks in Planner?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this feature is currently available out-of-the-box.  However, you can build a [Poower Automation Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) or [Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) that integrates the two of them.

In the long run, I would suggest that you remove Planner from the equation, and just use the kanban board in Azure DevOps for task management. You can display the kanban board inside Teams as well.